# Matplotlib 2D bar with scatter not lining up as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to create a 2D bar chart similar to what shown in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/bars3d.html).

In the code below, I expected the scatter points to be at the bottom of each bar, but it looks like it is plotting everything along y=0. I also expected the tops of the bars to vary/step, not the bottoms.

(And I also want to have the bars be the same color as the scatters, but I haven't started on that problem yet.)

```
x = np.arange(25)
y = -x
z = x/15
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.bar(x, y, z, zdir='y', alpha=0.8)
ax.scatter(x, y, s=45, c=z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set(ylabel='y')
ax.set(xlabel='x')
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data generation
# I changed y=-x to y=x. In the former case,
# the bottoms of the bars varied. This is because
# you plot them with negative values! So, the bars
# are being drawn from the x,y-plane at zero to an
# x,y-plane BELOW the zero plane. If you use y=x 
# instead, the bars are drawn from the x,y-plan at
# zero to an x,y-plane ABOVE zero!
x = np.arange(25)
y = x
z = x/15

# Initiate figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Generate the viridis color map with as many color
# values as the size of the x-array (or the y-array)
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis')
colors = np.zeros((x.size, 4))

for i in range(x.size):
    colors[i,:] = cmap(i / x.size)
    
# Loop over the different x- and y-values. Plot each
# combination separately with a zs value equal to the
# current y-value. Use the iterator 'i' to extract the
# proper color from the 'colors' matrix
for i, (xval, yval) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    # Even though we only have one x-value and one y-value,
    # these must be arrays (otherwise Axes.bar throws and
    # error)!
    ax.bar([xval], [yval], zs=yval, zdir='y', color=colors[i], alpha=0.8)

ax.scatter(x, y, s=45, c=z, cmap='viridis')

ax.set(ylabel='y')
ax.set(xlabel='x')

plt.show()
```

To start with, the bottoms of the bars vary/step because the values in your `y` array are negative! This means that the bars are being drawn for the x,y-plane at z=0 to an x,y-plane at a negative z-value. So, this behaviour is as expected. If you want the bars to vary/step at the top, you should change the line `y = -x` to `y = x`.

The issue regarding your scatter points is also solved by changing the `y` array to be positive, since the bars will then point 'upwards' while originating from the x,y-plane at z=0.

For the colors of the bars, we first store the viridis colormap (or any other colormap you want to use) in a variable called `cmap`. Then, we allocate a `color` matrix with as many rows as you have data points and four columns (r, g, b, a). Using a `for` loop, we obtain the colors from the aforementioned colormap. Note that you need to supply a normalized value to the colormap (*i.e.* a value in the range [0, 1]) in order to get a color. For this normalized value, we simply use the value of the iteration variable divided by the total size of your data. We use the color in the call to `Axes.bar`.

If I run the code above, I get the following output:
[image: Output plot]

Just as a side node, if you want to plot the scatter points at the top of the bars, you need to supply a value for the z-value of the scatter points (in this case, that value would simply equal to value in your `y`-array). Currently, you plot the scatter points in 2D (as you only supply x- and y-values, all scatter points are located at the x,y-plane at z=0). Say we would change the call to `Axes.scatter` to:

```
# For a 3D situation, you need to give three dimensions to the Axes.scatter 
# function in order for it to plot in 3D (previously, you only had 'x, y').
# Since the z-value should equal the y-value in this case, we now have 
# 'x, y, y'.
ax.scatter(x, y, y, s=45, c=z, cmap='viridis')
```

After this change, the output looks as follows:

[image: Output plot for which ax.scatter was varied]

Comment: thanks for the clear and detailed solution! The only thing I would add is that the y values are actually negative, so `y=-x` is correct/necessary; but adding `ax.invert_zaxis()` keeps the negative y and plots the bars such that they vary at the top.

Comment: @a11 Very good addition! I automatically assumed that the data should be positive, but you are completely right that it is also possible for negative values if you just invert the axis!